# oozie workflow is scheduling each 1 minute instead of 10 mins in Azure HDInsight Spark2 cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, oozie, azure-hdinsight

I have scheduled my oozie workflow in using coordinator.xml in Azure HDInsight cluster.

The time interval for spark job which was scheduled by oozie is 10 minutes, but My spark job is running every one minute.

my coordinator.properties:

```
startTime=2017-07-04T12:49Z
endTime=2017-07-05T12:44Z
timeZone=UTC
concurrency=1
frequency=12
workflowRoot=${oozie.coord.application.path}
nameNode=wasb://demospark-2017-07-04t05-15-35-507z@edmsparkdemo.blob.core.windows.net
jobTracker=hn0-edmspa.xxxsdf.hx.internal.cloudapp.net:8050
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
Spark_Master=yarn
Spark_Mode=cluster
Spark_Driver=locationDataMetrics.IdentificationMetrics
numExecutors=2
driverMemory=4G
executorMemory=2G
executorCores=2
workflowRoot=wasb://demospark-2017-07-04t05-15-35-507z@demospark.blob.core.windows.net/datainput9
oozie.coord.application.path=wasb://demospark-2017-07-04t05-15-35-507z@demospark.blob.core.windows.net/datainput9
sparkJar=demospark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

my coordinator.xml file :

```
<coordinator-app end="${endTime}" frequency="${frequency}" name="oozieTimeCoordinator" start="${startTime}" timezone="${timeZone}" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
  <controls>
    <concurrency>${concurrency}</concurrency>
  </controls>
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${workflowRoot}</app-path>
    </workflow>
  </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

How can I modify this oozie workflow scheduler to schedule in 10 or 15 minutes?

Comment: An alternate way to define `frequency` is to use CRON notation, e.g. `5/15 * * * * ` will start a Workflow 4 times per hour, at 05 - 20 - 35 - 50 minutes on wall time. It's a bit more predictable. Cf. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4.3._Cron_syntax_in_coordinator_frequency

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify frequency=240 and check whether the Oozie workflow scheduler is scheduled according to ten minutes?

For more details, refer "how to specify the scheduling in Oozie":

[Scheduling jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-oozie-linux-mac#scheduling-jobs)

[Frequency and Time=-Period Representation in Oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4._Frequency_and_Time-Period_Representation).

Comment: That 2nd link points to a *very* old version of Oozie... V3.1.3 was released almost 5 years ago, and the current stable version is 4.3 (cf. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/)